# Reset a form in html5 with submit

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to not reseting a form when you click a submit input type. You know that when you click the submit button in html5, all the form is converted to blankspaces, is it possible to not reseting it keeping the old values?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your language like php, if it is a request with POST method it will be stored in a global array $_POST['field_name'], get $_GET['field_name'],

You can use it to retain your values.
So which language are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaScript... any function there?

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see it, thanks a lot but i do not need help because i decided to change the html file. However, my doubt came from the submit input type of html. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help and your compromise!!! :))